# Avoid laravel global scope on specific queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `stuents` tablle with 3 columns `graduated` , `leaver` and `deleted_at`.

graduated and leaver are int (1) with null as default value. When a student graduates or leaves the school, the corresponding columns becomes 1.

When i use

```
$students=Student::get();
```

I need to only return Student where `graduated` and `leaver` are null, so I create two global scopes:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

     static::addGlobalScope('onlyGraduated', function ($builder) {
        $builder->where('graduated', null);
    });
    static::addGlobalScope('onlyLeaver', function ($builder) {
        $builder->where('leaver', null);
    }); 
}
```

This works for most use cases, but what should I do for some specific queries when I want the students thar are graduated? such as

```php
Students::where("graduated",1)->get();
```

Comment: "it work only in returned data but how to get" get what? what are you trying to ask?

Comment: @AndySong get trashed data i get answer , by withoutGlobalScope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to avoid a global scope in a specific query, yuu should use `withoutGlobalScope`:

```php
Students::withoutGlobalScope('onlyGraduated')->where("graduated",1)->get();
```

---

I would create a local scope in your Model called `graduated` and `leaver`:

```php
public function scopeGraduated($query) {
  return $query->withoutGlobalScope('onlyGraduated')->where("graduated",1);
}

public function scopeLeavers($query) {
  return $query->withoutGlobalScope('onlyLeaver')->where("leaver",1);
}
```

Then you will be able to query the data using:

```php
Students::get(); // Only students with both graduated and leaver null
Students::graduated()->get(); // Students with leaver null and graduated 1
Students::leavers()->get(); // Students with leaver 1 and graduated null
```